# Can't run route when running node.js as a proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, proxy

I use nginx as the server, and node.js as a proxy(listen:3000), there is a route called user, code likes following

```
exports.index = function (req, res){
  res.render('user', {
        id: req.params.id
    });
};
```

if I run http://domain.com:3000/user/1, http://domain.com:3000/user/2 ... it works well, but if i run http://domain.com/user/1, http://domain.com/user/2 ... it shows error '404', and http://domain.com runs well, so how to fixed it?

the nginx config:

```
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    if ($host = 'www.domain.com' ) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$  http://domain.com/$1   permanent;
    }


    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
```

Comment: What's in nginx config?

Comment: @alexeyten please look at my update